# Source code for the Android Wi-Fi settings activity?

Tags: android, settings

Looking through the massive android source code, anyone on here who know where exactly the above mentioned Activity is located? I would guess some place around

```
platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/app
```

but I cannot find anything.

Comment: Have you tried `platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi`? I've never really looked into it, but it looks like a good bet. ( https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi )

Comment: Hmm, I am looking for the actual activity they use, doesn't seem to be anything like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in the Settings app source code, specifically:

```
platform_packages_apps_settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiSettings.java
```

It can be found on Github here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiSettings.java